Jquery DataTable not working after appending the html code to DataTable using jQuery
I have created a datatable and appending the data to that datatable body , data appending successfully but the datatable not working properly
ex: If I click on the datatable header columns the entire table data is erasing.
Here is my full logic
Asp.net code:
<asp:Button ID="sb_add" runat="server" OnClientClick="return SB_Add_Legs(event);" Text="+ ADD" CssClass="btn btn-primary w-100 w-md-auto text-center px-4" />


<table class="table table-borderless rowSpace table-round-row dtr-inline  SB_table dataTable nowrap "
                    id="strastrategy_builder_datatable" style="width: 100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Action</th>
                            <th>Instrument</th>
                            <th>Expiry</th>
                            <th>Strike</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Future Price</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Delta</th>
                            <th>Gamma</th>
                            <th>Theta</th>
                            <th>Vega</th>
                            <th>IV</th>
                            <th data-dt-order="disable"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="sbnolegs">NO LEGS ADDED</div>

Datatable logic :
$("#strastrategy_builder_datatable").find("th").off("click.DT");
    $('#strastrategy_builder_datatable').DataTable({
        ordering: false,
        info: false,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        responsive: true,
        language: {
            emptyTable: ' ',
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                width: '100px',
                responsivePriority: 1,
                targets: 0
            },

            {
                className: 'dt-center',
                width: '50px',
                responsivePriority: 2,
                targets: -1
            },
            {
                width: '110px',
                // responsivePriority: 3,
                targets: -2
            },
            {
                width: '110px',
                responsivePriority: 4,
                targets: -3
            },
            {
                width: '110px',
                responsivePriority: 5,
                targets: -4
            },
            {
                width: '110px',
                responsivePriority: 6,
                targets: -5
            },
            {
                width: '110px',
                responsivePriority: 7,
                targets: -6
            },
            {
                width: '100px',
                responsivePriority: 8,
                targets: -7
            },
            {
                width: '100px',
                responsivePriority: 9,
                targets: -8
            },
            {
                width: '120px',
                responsivePriority: 10,
                targets: -9
            },
            {
                width: '120px',
                // responsivePriority: 10,
                targets: -10
            },
            {
                width: '160px',
                // responsivePriority: 10,
                targets: -11
            },
            {
                width: '100px',
                // responsivePriority: 10,
                targets: -12
            }

        ]
    });


Add button logic function:
function SB_Add_Legs(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log("data :- " + data);



    var d_stg = '';

    var s_leg_data = "";

    var b_selected = '';
    var s_selected = '';

    var ddl_expdate = "";
    var ddl_strike = "";

    //$("#strastrategy_builder_datatable").removeClass('hidden');

    var lnt = $("#strastrategy_builder_datatable .aliceBlueRow").length;

    //if (lnt === 1)

    if (lnt < 10) {

        var s = $("#sb_smbl_srch").val(); // textbox val
        var s_bs = $("#sb_buysell").val();   // dropdown val
        var s_inst = $("#sb_instrument").val(); // dropdown val
        var s_stk = $("#sb_strikeprice").val(); // dropdown val
        var s_ex = $("#sb_expdate").val(); // dropdown val
        var s_q = $("#sb_qty").val(); // textbox val

        d_stg = LTP_AJAXCall(s, s_ex, s_stk, s_inst, s_bs);
        
         console.log(d_stg);
/*[
    {
        "Price": "137.45",
        "Delta": "0.5085",
        "Gamma": "0.0012",
        "Theta": "-24.5206",
        "Vega": "8.1152",
        "IV": "16.64",
        "OI": "1637425.00",
        "OIChg": "835625.00",
        "FuturePrice": "22559",
        "StrikeType": "ATM",
        "LotSize": "25"
    }
]*/
        
        //SB_Legs_Added_Load("add", d_stg);

        //$("#strastrategy_builder_datatable tbody").empty();
        if (d_stg && d_stg.length > 0) {



            $.each(d_stg, function (index, rowData) {

                ddl_expdate = "";
                ddl_strike = "";

                if (s_bs.toLowerCase() === 'buy') b_selected = 'selected', s_selected = ''; else b_selected = '', s_selected = 'selected';

                var drpInstrumentValue = s_inst.toUpperCase();
                var d_exp = s_ex;
                var d_stk = s_stk;

                var ddl_inst = `
                    <option value="CE" ${drpInstrumentValue === "CE" ? "selected" : ""}>CE</option>
                    <option value="PE" ${drpInstrumentValue === "PE" ? "selected" : ""}>PE</option>
                    <option value="FUT" ${drpInstrumentValue === "FUT" ? "selected" : ""}>FUT</option>
                    <option value="EQ" ${drpInstrumentValue === "EQ" ? "selected" : ""}>EQ</option>
                   `;

                var e_date = ExpDates_AJAXCall(s, drpInstrumentValue);
                if (e_date && e_date.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < e_date.length; i++)
                        if (d_exp == e_date[i].ExpDate)
                            ddl_expdate += `<option selected value="${e_date[i].ExpDate}">${e_date[i].ExpDate}</options>`;
                        else
                            ddl_expdate += `<option value="${e_date[i].ExpDate}">${e_date[i].ExpDate}</options>`;
                }

                var stk = Strikes_AJAXCall(s, drpInstrumentValue, d_exp);
                if (stk && stk.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < stk.length; i++)
                        if (d_stk == stk[i].StrikePrice)
                            ddl_strike += `<option selected value="${stk[i].StrikePrice}">${stk[i].StrikePrice}</options>`;
                        else
                            ddl_strike += `<option value="${stk[i].StrikePrice}">${stk[i].StrikePrice}</options>`;
                }

                s_leg_data += SB_Generate_Legs_Added_HTML(b_selected, s_selected, ddl_inst, ddl_expdate,
                    ddl_strike, s_q, rowData.FuturePrice, rowData.Price, rowData.Delta, rowData.Gamma, rowData.Theta, rowData.Vega, rowData.IV);;


            });

            $(".sbnolegs").hide();
            $("#sb_groupbtns, #sb_netpremium_spread").show();
            $("#strastrategy_builder_datatable tbody").append(s_leg_data);
            SB_CalculateNetPremium();
        }

    }
    else {
        $("#perrormsg").html('');
        $("#perrormsg").html('You can add only a maximum of 10 rows');
        $("#modelpopupmsg").modal("show");
    }

    //return false;

}


And the html code return function is:
function SB_Generate_Legs_Added_HTML(b_selected, s_selected, inst, ddl_expdate, ddl_strike, Qty, FuturePrice, Price, Delta, Gamma, Theta, Vega, IV) {

    return `<tr class="aliceBlueRow">
              <td>
                  <div class="d-inline-block ">
                      <select class="form-select border-0 analyserfields" name="sbaction" onchange="SB_Legs_Added_table_val_change('ddl',this);">
                          <option value="Buy" ${b_selected}>BUY</option>
                          <option value="Sell" ${s_selected}>Sell</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <select class="form-select border-0 analyserfields" name="sbinst" onchange="SB_Legs_Added_table_val_change('ddl',this);">
                      ${inst}
                  </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <select class="form-select border-0 analyserfields" name="sbexp" onchange="SB_Legs_Added_table_val_change('ddl',this);">
                      ${ddl_expdate}
                  </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <select class="form-select border-0 analyserfields" name="sbstrike" onchange="SB_Legs_Added_table_val_change('ddl',this);">
                      ${ddl_strike}
                  </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap v-line pe-3">
                      <span class="input-group-text border-0"><i class="bi bi-dash textDanger pointer" onclick="SB_Legs_Added_table_minqty(${Qty},this);"></i></span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center border-0 analyserfields" name="sbqty" value=${Qty} autocomplete="off"
                          style="min-width: 40px; max-width: 80px" maxlength='6' onblur="SB_Add_Leg_QtyValue(this);" oninput="SB_calculateqtylivenetprem('qty',this);"/>
                      <span class="input-group-text border-0"><i class="bi bi-plus textSuccess pointer" onclick="SB_Legs_Added_table_maxqty(${Qty},this);"></i></span>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 analyserfields" name="sbfprice"  value=${FuturePrice}
             autocomplete="off" oninput="SB_Legs_Added_table_val_change('futprice',this);"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 analyserfields" name="sbprice"  value=${Price}
                  autocomplete="off" oninput="SB_Legs_Added_table_val_change('price',this);"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 dull-pastel-greenBG analyserfields" name="sbdelta"
                    value=${Delta}  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" disabled/>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 dull-pastel-greenBG analyserfields" name="sbgamma"
                      value=${Gamma}  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" disabled/>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 dull-pastel-greenBG analyserfields" name="svtheta"
                       value=${Theta}  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" disabled/>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 dull-pastel-greenBG analyserfields" name="sbvega"
                     value=${Vega}  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" disabled/>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 analyserfields" name="sbiv" autocomplete="off"
                      value=${IV}  oninput="SB_Legs_Added_table_val_change('iv',this);" />
              </td>
              <td>
                  <a href="javascript://" class="px-2 py-1 fs-6 analyserfields" name="sbdelete" onclick="SB_DeleteLegs(event,this)">
                      <i class="bx bxs-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                  </a>
              </td>
             </tr>`;
}


My concept is if I click on the add button the function return SB_Generate_Legs_Added_HTML html code should append to datatable strastrategy_builder_datatable and the data is appending but if I click on the header columns the entire table data is erasing.
where is the mistake? how to achieve this concept?

You should not add rows by appending HTML, you must add using the datatables row.add()
Here is an example of your code with that function:


      $("#strastrategy_builder_datatable").find("th").off("click.DT");      
      table = $("#strastrategy_builder_datatable").DataTable({
        ordering: true,
        info: false,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        responsive: true,
        language: {
          emptyTable: " ",
        },
        columnDefs: [
          {
            width: "100px",
            responsivePriority: 1,
            targets: 0,
          },

          {
            className: "dt-center",
            width: "50px",
            responsivePriority: 2,
            targets: -1,
          },
          {
            width: "110px",
            // responsivePriority: 3,
            targets: -2,
          },
          {
            width: "110px",
            responsivePriority: 4,
            targets: -3,
          },
          {
            width: "110px",
            responsivePriority: 5,
            targets: -4,
          },
          {
            width: "110px",
            responsivePriority: 6,
            targets: -5,
          },
          {
            width: "110px",
            responsivePriority: 7,
            targets: -6,
          },
          {
            width: "100px",
            responsivePriority: 8,
            targets: -7,
          },
          {
            width: "100px",
            responsivePriority: 9,
            targets: -8,
          },
          {
            width: "120px",
            responsivePriority: 10,
            targets: -9,
          },
          {
            width: "120px",
            // responsivePriority: 10,
            targets: -10,
          },
          {
            width: "160px",
            // responsivePriority: 10,
            targets: -11,
          },
          {
            width: "100px",
            // responsivePriority: 10,
            targets: -12,
          },
        ],
      });    

      function SB_Add_Legs(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        table.row
          .add([
            "b_selected",
            "s_selected",
            "ddl_inst",
            "ddl_expdate",
            "ddl_strike",
            "s_q",
            "rowData.FuturePrice",
            "rowData.Price",
            "rowData.Delta",
            "rowData.Gamma",
            "rowData.Theta",
            "rowData.Vega",
            "rowData.IV",
          ])
          .draw(false);

        $(".sbnolegs").hide();
        $("#sb_groupbtns, #sb_netpremium_spread").show();
      }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.6/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.6/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="SB_Add_Legs(event)">ADD</button>

    <table
      class="table table-borderless rowSpace table-round-row dtr-inline SB_table dataTable nowrap"
      id="strastrategy_builder_datatable"
      style="width: 100%"
    >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Action</th>
          <th>Instrument</th>
          <th>Expiry</th>
          <th>Strike</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Future Price</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Delta</th>
          <th>Gamma</th>
          <th>Theta</th>
          <th>Vega</th>
          <th>IV</th>
          <th data-dt-order="disable"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="sbnolegs">NO LEGS ADDED</div>

  </body>
</html>



